# How to prove that the following morphism is surjective?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R = k[x,y]$, where $k$ is a field. Let $g_0$ upto $g_n$ be homogeneous elements in $R$ of degree $d$ such that the $g_i$ have no common factors. Let $\phi: R(-d)^{n+1}_m \to R_m$ given by $$(a_0,\ldots, a_n) \mapsto \sum a_ig_i,$$ where $R(-d)_l = R_{l-d}$ and the index to the lower right $m$ denotes the $m$'th graded piece of $R$. This map should be surjective for sufficiently large $m$, but I can't prove it at the time being. I have tried to construct elements that map to the monomials of degree $m$, but to no avail. A clean proof or hints that could lead to a clean proof would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For $d=m$ this means that $G$'s span $R_m$ (as a vector space over $k$); since $\dim R_m=m+1$, this implies $n\geq m$. So I suppose some assumptions are missing in your question.

Comment: Thanks. We should have m >> 0.

Comment: The image of $\phi$ is $\sum_{i=0}^n R_{m-d}g_i$. What if $n=0$, $d=1$, $g_0=x$? Then we should have $R_{m-1}x=R_m$ and what about $y^m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assume $n\ge 1$. In fact, you only need to consider this case as we will see later. Consider the exact sequence 
$$0\to R(-d)^{n+1} \hookrightarrow R \twoheadrightarrow R/(g_0,\ldots,g_n) \to 0$$
You want to show that $R/(g_0,\ldots,g_n)$ vanishes in high degree. This is equivalent to this ring being Artin, i.e. the corresponding zero locus $Z_+(g_0,\ldots,g_n)$ is a finite set. Now, I claim that $g_1$ is not a zero divisor or a unit in $R/(g_0)$. Clearly, we do not have $g_1\in(g_0)$ because that directly contradicts them being coprime. If it were a unit then $1-g_1\in (g_0)$ would mean $1\in(g_0)$ because the ideal is homogeneous, also impossible. If $g_1$ would become a (nonzero) zero divisor, then we'd have some $f_1$ with $f_1g_1\in (g_0)$, so $f_1g_1=f_0g_0$. Since the irreducible factors of $g_0$ do not occur anywhere in the factorization of $g_1$, they would all have to appear in the factorization of $f_1$, so $f_1\in(g_0)$.

Note that $Z_+(g_0)$ has dimension one. The vanishing of $g_1$ on $Z_+(g_0)$ is therefore a finite set, which is what we needed to show.

More algebraically put, let $I=(g_0,\ldots,g_n)$. We have found a regular sequence of length $2$, so $2\le\operatorname{grade}(I)\le\operatorname{ht}(I)$ and $\dim(R/I)+\operatorname{ht}(I)=\dim(R)=2$, implying $\dim(R/I)=0$.